# How to use the store value in testrigor using AI Generation

Tags: testrigor

Have stored a value in variableName at step 1 and next step trying to use it with below command
`extract text from stored value "variableName" matching regex pattern "\b\d{6}\b" and save it as "otp"`

But getting below error AI wasn't able to generate steps for 'extract text from stored value "variableName" matching regex pattern "\b\d{6}\b" and save it as "otp"'

Answer (score 0):

The command is actually wrong, so tR thinks it is AI promt.

There are various ways to grab value. Here is the whole list I have mentioned in the link below.

ex: extract value by regex "regex" from saved value "variableFrom" and save it as "variableTo"

https://testrigor.com/docs/language/#extract